# Website Downloads a File instead of Loading Index

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an issue on my website , its downloading the entire index file instead of loading it , i think its a htaccess issue , but I don't know what to add or to remove , could you please help , this is my htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
</ifModule>
### INTERDIRE L'AFFICHAGE DE CERTAINS FORMATS DE FICHIER 
### EXÉCUTÉS PAR LE SERVEUR MAIS INTERDIT D'AFFICHAGE PAR LE NAVIGATEUR WEB
<Files ~ "\.(inc|class|sql|ini|conf|exe|dll|bin|tpl|bkp|dat|c|h|py|spd|theme|module)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php54/lib
</IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

Comment: Show us the raw HTTP response headers. Use curl or Postman or the browsers network inspector.

Comment: Remove `.htaccess` file and see if it resolves the issue. If it does then its a issue in htaccess otherwise it could be permission issue

Comment: i removed htaccess and yes its showing content of index.php

Comment: but i need the htccess file , to ensure redirects and script works on php54

Comment: I could imagine that your hosting provider has abandoned php 5.4 support. You should check with him which php version is to be used now and edit `suPHP_ConfigPath` in your .htaccess file correspondingly.

Comment: @digijay , exactly that's what happened , they abandonned php 5.4 , i must use from php 5.5 >